Is it possible to flip the electric charge of elementary particles using a strong laser, then use it to produce energy via annihilation?
I am hoping that there could be cases where the energy imput is less the output to make this work. I would imagine that flipping a charge doesn't take excessive energy- as it only involves a spin flip which might not be an energy costly process.The conversion to energy is complete in this case- better than fission or fusion processes.

Antimatter is not the spin flipped version of normal matter, a spin up and spin down electron are not antiparticles

Flipping the spin of an electron does not change its charge, neither does it turn an electron into a positron. You seem to be conflating several distinct concepts.

Fundamentally this process would also violate energy conservation, if the matter-antimatter conversion process takes less than $mc^2$ energy per unit mass (i.e. if this would work).

The spin in the question(not necessarily of an electron) refers to angular momentum which is in the direction of magnetic dipole moment which depends on the direction of rotation as well as the sign of the electric charge.

A laser will not flip the charge of a particle. That would violate the conservation of charge. It might flip the spin of a particle, but that is something very different and does not convert it into an particle.
